# R - Argument is missing with no default even with explicit null checking

Tags: r

I hope this question isn't as basic as the title makes it seem.  I've been working with R for a few months now but I can't seem to figure out what's going on here.  I'm reading an extremely large dataset and trying to convert the columns to the correct data type.  I have four columns that I believe are just numeric but it seems there's some bad data in here somewhere. When reading these columns as numeric I see this issue:

scan() expected 'a real', got '"2'

Seems simple enough, so I wrote this method to very safely strip any quotes that may exist in the column:

```
setAs("character", "num_strip_quote",
      function(from) {
        coerceString = NA
        if(!is.null(from)){
          coerceString = from
        }
        as.numeric(gsub('"'), "", coerceString)
    }
)
```

And here's my read.csv method:

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = c("NA", ""),
             colClasses = c(rep("character", 3),
                            rep("num_strip_quote", 1), 
                            rep("character", 3), 
                            rep("num_strip_dollar_comma", 3), 
                            rep("character", 3),
                            "num_strip_dollar_comma", 
                            rep("character", 4), 
                            "num_strip_dollar_comma", 
                            "date"))
```

I've isolated the issue to the fourth column at this point.  Still when I run this I get this error:

Error in gsub("\"") : argument "x" is missing, with no default

I don't see how a missing or null value is getting through, but it seems like it is.  Any idea what I missed?

Comment: Look at `?gsub` then look at the parentheses in `as.numeric(gsub('"'), "", coerceString)`

Comment: Well, I'm embarrassed.  Thank you for the eagle eye review there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original call to remove the quotations from the strings was:

as.numeric(gsub('"'), "", coerceString)

I put an additional paren into the gsub method which caused the call to have only one param instead of the required three.  It should've been:

as.numeric(gsub('"', "", coerceString))